# How do I reference a preference option by key in my PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, kotlin, key, preference, preferencescreen

I have a preference screen, and I want to disable visibility of a preference setting programaticaly in OnCreate depending of which version of android we are using.
In order to do that I must be able to reference that particular preference object.

While I see a lot of examples using findPreference() I see that that method is deprecated and Android studio doesn't suggest any similar method.

I don't know how you reference a preference by key other than that.

Here is my activity:

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

```
val Tag = "My Activity:"

companion object {
    private val TAG_TITLE = "PREFERENCE_ACTIVITY"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val pManager = SharedPreferencesManager(this)
    pManager.loadTheme()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_preference, MainPreference()).commit()
    } else {
        title = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(TAG_TITLE)
    }

    supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
            setTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
    setUpToolbar()

}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)

}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    outState.putCharSequence(TAG_TITLE, title)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    if (supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

private fun setUpToolbar() {
    supportActionBar?.setTitle("Settings")
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
}

class MainPreference : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }

}

override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
    recreate()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be referring to the non support library versions of the preferences API which are indeed going to be deprecated after API 29. However in `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, `findPreference` is still the approach you should be using.

You can have a look at the method documentation here: [`findPreference(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)).